# Greatest common divisor of consecutive square free numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures

I guess that every prime number occurs as the greatest common divisor of two consecutive square free numbers, which I don't expect a proof of.

But I've done some experiments indicating that:

> If $m, n$ are consecutive square free numbers then  $\gcd(m, n)$ is not composite.

Is that true and can it be proved?

Comment: If $m=p_1p_2k$ and $n=p_1p_2(k+1)$, so that $\gcd(m,n)=p_1p_2$,then you require $p_1p_2-1$ consecutive non-square-free numbers if $m,n$ are to be consecutive square-free positive integers. The smallest that $p_1p_2$ can be is $6$. It is claimed that arbitrarily long sequences of non-square-free numbers occur, but they occur at significantly large magnitudes. See [OEIS A045882](http://oeis.org/A045882)

Comment: @KeithBackman: It's not just claimed – see the proof in the Wikipedia section I linked to under lulu's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Barring miscalculation we have $$\gcd(28331962460555993122305,28331962460555993122290)=15$$

And these two numbers are consecutive square free integers.  Indeed we can obtain the relevant factorings via [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5Bfactor+28331962460555993122290%2Bn%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C15%7D%5D).

This example was constructed out of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, using $$\text {ChineseRemainder}[(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,14),$$$$(15,4,7^2,9,11^2,25,13^2,17^2,19^2,23^2,29^2,31^2)]$$  in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ChineseRemainder%5B%280%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C10%2C11%2C14%29%2C%2815%2C4%2C7%5E2%2C9%2C11%5E2%2C25%2C13%5E2%2C17%5E2%2C19%5E2%2C23%5E2%2C29%5E2%2C31%5E2%29%5D)

Comment: I was just about to start doing the same thing :-) Is there a reason why you used $15$ and not $12=2^2\cdot3$? (I'm aware that $6=2\cdot3$ wouldn't work.) (I mean as the difference of the two numbers, obviously not as their $\gcd$, which would have to be $6$.)

Comment: @joriki  Well...when I realized that $6$ failed I gave up on even factors immediately.  This might have been too hasty.

Comment: The problem with $6=2\cdot3$ is that it forces one of the numbers to be multiples of $4=2^2$, since there are no other residues of $2$ to move to. But with difference $12=2^2\cdot3$ both numbers can be free of $2^2$.

Comment: Indeed with ChineseRemainder $[(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10,-11),(5^2,2^2,3^2,7^2,11^2,13^2,17^2,19^2,23^2,29^2,31^2)]$
we get $\gcd(30721170216859104770574,30721170216859104770574+12)=6$.

Comment: @joriki  Ah, good.  That's better.

Comment: See also [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution) for this construction.

Comment: @joriki Maybe someone will vandalize that Wikipedia page soon, if not already! Mwahahahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: So you are taking "consecutive square free numbers" to mean "square free numbers with no other square free numbers between them", rather than "square free numbers with no other numbers between them"?

Comment: @Acccumulation  Oh, yes.  If the latter definition was intended the gcd would always be $1$, as any two consecutive integers are relatively prime.