# Identify what is being proved based on solution to problem

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, self-learning, advice

I can't identify what is being proved when I look at the solution manual for each problem and the solution doesn't refer to the problem statement directly, i.e. give the assumption and  restate the conclusion.

How do I identify what's being proved or what's the purpose of the proof just by looking at the solution?

I think that if I can figure out how to go from the solution of the problem to the problem statement then I'll be able to do the inverse operation, i.e. proofs.

I find that the problems and the proofs are actually restatements of each other. The problem to prove is a summarized and really convoluted way to stating the proof.

Comment: I think this is too vague to answer in general.  Yes, of course, solutions are often written under the assumption that the reader has the problem in hand.  Without that, I'm sure the solutions can be hard to read.  Do you have a particular instance in mind?

Comment: But shouldn't you be able to figure out what problem the solution was trying to prove? Otherwise, did you even understand the solution?

Comment: Why?  I'd expect the solution to use terms without identifying them...as the author assumes that you have the definition from the problem statement.

Comment: that would be a really bad solution , don't you think?

Comment: Not at all.  Why repeat definitions that were given elsewhere?  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507935/greatest-common-divisor-of-consecutive-square-free-numbers/3508015#3508015) for instance is a problem I answered recently.  I can't imagine that anyone could guess what the question was from what I wrote.  Happily, though, the question is right there.

Comment: I'd go a bit further and say that definitions should not be repeated unless clarifying the definition is important.  After all, either you repeat the definition as it appeared (in which case, what was the point?) or you change the definition (in which case you risk introducing errors or confusion).  If your intent is to use the definition as given, just use it by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just not possible, in general, to determine the problem statement given the solution, as printed in the solution manual.

For example, here is a solution:

> The equation reduces, modulo $9$, to
>
> $x^3\equiv5\pmod9$,
>
> which has no solutions. Therefore, the original equation has no solutions.

There is simply no way to determine what the question was, since all of the information about the original equation, besides its residue modulo $9$, has been erased.

So, I'm not sure whether or not trying to deduce the problem given the solution is a valuable way to spend your time.

The source for the above solution is [Gerry Myerson's community wiki answer to "Awfully sophisticated proof for simple facts."](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44748) (Gerry's answer contains the problem, too!)

Comment: If it's not possible, in general to determine the problem given the solution, then how do you know the solution even solves or address the problem? How is 42 the answer to the meaning of life? What about 45? Needless to say 42 isn't much of use?

Comment: Well, you can look at the solution *and* the problem and see whether or not the solution solves the problem. If you look at the problem that my answer talks about (which is "Solve the Diophantine equation $x^3-117y^3=5$.") along with the solution, you can verify that the solution does, in fact, solve the problem.